# "Avionic Engineering" vs "Avionics Engineering"

Tags: phrase-usage

I am searching for the correct phrase usage of an engineering department's name i.e. "**Department of Avionics Engineering**".
Shouldn't it be "**Department of Avionic Engineering**"?

Because we always have "**Department of Electronic Engineering**" instead of "**Department of Electronics Engineering**".

Would you please mention the English grammar rule with a proper reference that explains such usage of noun phrases? I wasn't able to find that English grammar rule from a worth-mentioning reference.

Comment: Grammar doesn't apply: it is their name. If they choose to call it X then that's it's name.

Comment: Uh I deleted the first comment because I'm not sure if "Avionic" is an actual word.  In your other example it could be "Department of Electronic Engineering" or (informally) "Department of Electronics".

Comment: @WeatherVane [Avionics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avionic). Plural noun (*avionics*), or singular adjective (*avionic*).

Comment: The word Avionic is an actual word that has been used as an adjective by the University of Liverpool, Cranfield University and a Wikipedia page on "Avionics".

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer to this question or please suggest another platform where I may get the answer.